# How to have centered columns in row Boostrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, row

How to have bigger gaps between columns in row in Bootstrap 4? I tried everything but its not centered good. Need that gaps to have centered columns. Because its looked awful.
Image Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Bkkp.png

Code :

```
    <section id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <h1>TEST</h1>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can add `text-center` class next to `container`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Comment: Yes but this centered all text, not just the columns.

Comment: If you mean the paragraphs, you can add that class to p tags.

Comment: I need to center the column, not the text. If I add text-center yes, its centering the text but its look awful.

Comment: I see. Indeed, your cards are centered. To better test, try adding a background color to your columns, e.g. add class `bg-info` next to `col-4`s or borders. Because the background colors of cards and their parent are same and because of the structure of your specific text, they "visually" seem misaligned. If you still want to move the contents of a card, you may add padding classses such `px-2`. Refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to like this ...??

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section >
        <div class="container  " >
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center  " >
            <div class="col-4 border  " >
              <h1>TEST</h1>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 border">
              <h1>TEST</h1>
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 border">
              <h1>TEST</h1>
              <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,</p>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First example:

- create a row ( `<div class="row">` ).
- add the desired number of columns (tags with appropriate `col-*-*` classes). The first star (`*`) represents the responsiveness: `sm`, `md`, `lg` or `xl`, while the second star represents a number, which should always add up to `12` for each row.